# Java Try/Catch Issues

Tags: java, error-handling

I'm relatively new with Java and I've always had problems with the Try/Catch functions in the code so I was wondering if you guys could help me out.

The issue I'm having is that I've written a try/catch but I get an error message saying that the exception is never thrown. I've written a similar statement in another part of my overall code that does work fine so I wonder what the issue is with this one then.

Here is the code:

```
public String getMatchedLogs(String matchStr, File logFile) {
    String fileLine = "";
    try {
        Scanner ipScan = new Scanner(fileLine);
        if (fileLine.indexOf(matchStr) > -1) {
            output += fileLine;
        }else{
            System.out.println(fileLine.indexOf(""));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());

    }
    return fileLine;
} //end getMatchedLogs
```

The error is in the catch where it says the exception is never thrown. So if you guys could give me some insight on what's going on I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: why you are scanning empty string and taking unused params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually doing anything with the parameter `File logFile`, you're only using the empty `String fileLine = "";` you defined.  Thus there's no file access going on, thus there's no chance of a `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 1):

Get in the habit of looking up methods to see if they do what you think they do.

The Scanner constructor for File objects opens a file and declares that it can throw FileNotFoundException
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)

The Scanner constructor for a String scans the string itself and does not open a file, so it won't need to throw the exception
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.lang.String)

By the way: Your code seems to be using the scanner to write to the String passed in ("filine"). Strings are immutable in Java, and can't change when passed into a method.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I'll be sure to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

`FileNotFound` exception is not thrown by the Scanner scanning lines. You are not using the `logFile` so there is no chance that `FileNotFoundException` can be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The java compiler may complain if you have a catch handler that the compiler knows can never occur. 
(Java exception rules tend to be pretty strict compared to newer languages such as Scala)

Answer (score 0):

You are catching a specific type of exception which is not getting thrown here.

So you should try:

```
catch (Exception e) {}
```

to catch any kind of exception.

Answer (score 0):

If any `Exception` other than `FileNotFoundException` not be able to catch in your case. it is better to use as follows..

```
     try {
        try {
            Scanner ipScan = new Scanner(fileLine);
            if (fileLine.indexOf(matchStr) > -1) {
                output += fileLine;
            } else {
                System.out.println(fileLine.indexOf(""));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // error log here
    }
```

Comment: If we can write multiple catch block then what is the advantage of using nested try-catch as per your answer?

Comment: @JqueryLearner actually it is depends on your needs. If you are willing to throw other exceptions other than a particular exception you don't want to use nested exceptions at all. But there are some cases, we don't want to throw what ever exceptions throws.

Comment: @Ruchira i mean to say we can write *catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // error log here
    }* so it will check both exceptions (in the OP case) but you use ed 2 try -catch and My question is one try and 2 catch

Comment: @JqueryLearner Both will give you the same results finally. also you can use `try{}catch(FileNotFoundException | Exception e){}`

Comment: You usually only want to catch an exception if you can do something about it. Why catch Exception? If you only log it, the program may be in an invalid state when it should've just crashed.

Comment: @leewangzhong it is up to you if you want to do something after exception throws you can add some logic there.

Comment: Then it's not better to catch Exception, in general, unless you INTEND to have your program continue after that. The default should be "don't catch Exception".

Comment: @leewangzhong it is up to you again .

Comment: I mean, it is not good to recommend that they catch Exception. The asker didn't give a reason to need to catch other exceptions. If you're saying it's a matter of opinion whether or not to catch Exception, I disagree: it is a matter of purpose, of the need to catch general exceptions in your specific application. The asker didn't show a need, so I don't think it's a good recommendation.

Comment: @leewangzhong You got my point wrong. In this case OP doesn't get desired Exception since he did this code wrong. At least he can figure out other kind of Exception been throwing from code block inside the try. If you are pretty sure about code you can use particular Exception or custom exception as you wish.

Comment: He would figure out what exception was thrown if the program crashed and printed a stacktrace as well. In this case, it was a compiler error.